# Android DrEdit Registration Of Google console api

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-console

I am creating Oauth 2.0 client id for DrEdit gdrive sample application.
I am doing everything as explained in Readme file of the repo. providing my SH1 certificate and giving package "com.example.android.notepad" , but when i am clicking on "create client id" then it is saying that "This client ID is globally unique and is already in use."
Please tell me how to setup this app and create client id for it.
Thanx

Comment: `com.example.android.notepad` is already in use ... change package name of you app

Answer (score 0):

(From comments, please give complete answers in the future)

`com.example.android.notepad` is already in use. Change the package name of you app.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little more detail Ali's correct answer:

You must change the package name in your **android manifest** file for it to work. You do not need to change the package names in the java files themselves.